# Java Swing mouse listener not working

Tags: java, swing, swingx

I would need to have a MouseListener active on a SwingX JXDatePicker component, enabling me to perform specific actions when the user clicks on the component.
Unfortunately the event is never triggered.

Hereby a small piece of code that reproduces the problem:

```
public class TestDummy4 extends JFrame implements MouseListener{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2424758762078571430L;

    public TestDummy4(){
        super();
        this.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        //Adds date picker
        JXDatePicker dp = new JXDatePicker();
        dp.getEditor().setEditable(false);
        dp.getEditor().setHighlighter(null);
        dp.addMouseListener(this);

        this.getContentPane().add(dp);
        this.pack();
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                //Builds GUI
                new TestDummy4();
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Mouse clicked");
    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Mouse pressed");
    }
    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {}
    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Mouse Entered");
    }
    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {}
}
```

With this code, I have not a single line of output on the console when clicking on the JXDatePicker.

Any help / hint would be greatly appreciated!
Thomas

Comment: same issue with all compound components (f.i. with core combo, see the tutorial): you can't add a low-level listeners to the parent and expect that it'll get notified on events to the children

Comment: *"Java Swing mouse listener.."*  Minor point, but `MouseListener` (like most listeners) is pure AWT.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To add a `MouseListener` to the `JXDatePicker's` editor component use:

```
dp.getEditor().addMouseListener(this);
```

*Update:* 
To add a `ActionListener` to the component's open `JButton` you can use:

```
JButton openButton = (JButton) dp.getComponent(1); 
openButton.addActionListener(myActionListener);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the swift reply: this works indeed when clicking on the editor but unfortunately it does not catch mouse clicks on the drop-down arrow next to it (also part of the JXDatePicker component)... any suggestions? Many thanks

Comment: Thx but unfortunately this doesn't work. To be more specific: I'm looking to add a listener on the component with the arrow that opens the month view (not the month view itself). Any other suggestions? Many thanks

Comment: beware: the button is an implementation detail that might change (no immediate plans, but .. it could) @Tom: the eternal question - why or what exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: _have to resort_ that's the question - most often the requirement can be met somehow else :-)